# How to walk a tree until a node is found, summing up attributes along the way

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, tree

I'm building a tree with arbitrary structure. Leaves of the tree have a particular attribute that no other nodes have. I'm trying to come up with a way to traverse the tree to find a particular leaf and keep a running sum of the attributes of the leaves I've visited. I need the cumulative sum of the leaves I've visited that *are not* the leaf I'm searching for, as well as the attribute of the leaf I am trying to find. I need it to search left-to-right, top-to-bottom.

An example tree might look something like this:[image]

My `Node` class is:

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, name, children=[], **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
        self.name = name
        self.children = children

    def insert(self, child):
        self.children.append(child)
```

If I built the example tree as

```py
l1 = Node("leaf1", attr=1)
l2 = Node("leaf2", attr=2)
n2 = Node("node2", children=[l1, l2])

l3 = Node("leaf3", attr=3)
l4 = Node("leaf4", attr=4)
n1 = Node("node1", children=[n2, l3, l4])


l6 = Node("leaf6", attr=6)
n4 = Node("node4", children=[l6])

l5 = Node("leaf5", attr=5)
l7 = Node("leaf7", attr=7)
n3 = Node("node3", children=[l5, n4, l7])

root = Node("root", children=[n1, n3])
```

and I wanted to `search_node(root, "leaf4")`, I'd expect a result of `(6, 4)` - the first element of the tuple is the sum of all leaves visited that were not leaf 4, and the second element is the attribute attached to leaf 4. `search_node(root, "leaf1")` would result in `(0, 1)`, as there were no leaves visited that were not leaf 1.

Here's the code that I have so far:

```py
def search_node(node, search_name):
    cum_sum = 0
    if node.children:
        for child in node.children:
            if child.name == search_name:
                return (cum_sum, child.attr)
            subtree_attr_sum, node_attr = search_node(child, search_name)
            if node_attr is not None:
                return (subtree_attr_sum, node_attr)
            else:
                cum_sum += subtree_attr_sum
        return (cum_sum, None)
    else:
        return (node.attr, None)
```

It seems to work on the left half of the tree, but not on the right half. Admittedly, this code is ugly and could probably be reduced.

Comment: I can't answer your question, but it seems to me that `else: return (node.attr, None)` is not useful and should be `else: return (cum_sum, None)`.

Comment: It's unrelated to your question (since you only omit a `children` arg in leaf nodes), but using an empty list as a default argument for `children` is probably unwise. If you tried to use it to promote a leaf node to a normal node, the `insert` method will end up adding children to that list, which is shared by *all* the leaves.

Comment: @Blckknght You were correct. My use-case is to generate a tree structure from a JSON file containing hierarchy mappings and node definitions. When trying to `insert` children into the root node, the node being `insert`ed recursively added itself to its `children` list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. A one-line modification in your code:

```
def search_node(node, search_name):
    cum_sum = 0
    if node.children:
        for child in node.children:
            if child.name == search_name:
                return (cum_sum, child.attr)
            subtree_attr_sum, node_attr = search_node(child, search_name)
            if node_attr is not None:
                return (cum_sum + subtree_attr_sum, node_attr) # THIS LINE
            else:
                cum_sum += subtree_attr_sum
        return (cum_sum, None)
    else:
        return (node.attr, None)
```

You made an oversight. You're not adding the cumulative sum to the result you got via recursion.

Also, a possible bug in your logic: Why are you not checking the root as well?

Comment: Yup, that was it, thanks! As for why I'm not checking the root - I'm only looking for leaves in the structure (and the function should probably be named `search_leaf` or something). I probably should do some error checking to guarantee that the tree itself is populated.